# How can I use the Factory pattern and expose my factories to consuming code without introducing transitive dependencies on the constructed types?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, dependencies, factory

I have a C# class called `FileTransferManager`. Previously it took some parameters such as a username and password to connect to a FTP server. However now I have an additional requirement to support login using a private key. I'm using the `Renci.SshNet` library for the file transfers. This library supports both methods of login, so that's not a problem. However, I decided to use the factory pattern to produce some classes from the library that I need to instantiate, such as `SftpClient` and `PrivateKeyFile`; these have several constructors to take various types of data, and I want to support multiple options.

My problem is that when I create an `IFactory<T>` interface and implement it, e.g. `PasswordSftpClientFactory : IFactory<SftpClient>`, I get errors in the code that calls my `FileTransferManager`, saying that I need to add a reference to `Renci.SshNet`. I was hoping to keep that library an "internal" dependency of `FileTransferManager` - not sure if that's the correct term, but I mean a dependency that does not "leak" to callers of `FileTransferManager`. I don't want to have to add a reference to an implementation detail of `FileTransferManager` just because I'm using the factory pattern.

So, how can I create a factory that produces the `SftpClient` and `PrivateKeyFile` objects without introducing a transitive dependency on `Renci.SshNet`? Is this where the `FactoryFactory` meme came from?

Comment: Factory pattern should not use generics. That your code uses generics tells me you are doing something wrong and that you misunderstood the factory pattern.

Comment: Oh, yeah, if I use an `ISftpClientFactory` interface, then I don't get the reference error.

Comment: This question would benefit greatly from an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean#:~:text=In%20context%2C%20MCVE%20is%20still,the%20error%20you're%20experiencing.). Show us some code. Your plain English description of the design does not tell us what is wrong.